# Slight syntax issues in python function, thought the formatting looks fine (python, line 7)

Tags: python

```
def product_of_positives(seq):
    positives=[]       
    p=1        
    for a in range (len(seq)):            
        if seq[a] > 0:                
            positives.append(seq(a)      
    for i in range (len(positives)):          
        p=p*positives[i]        
        print(p)  

seq=[1,2,3,4,5]
product_of_positives(seq)
```

Comment: please format your code with intentation like in your editor.

Comment: Ignoring the formatting, you have an unclosed `)` here: `positives.append(seq(a)`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a close parentheses, and your second set of parentheses should be square brackets:

```
positives.append(seq(a)
```

Should be:

```
positives.append(seq[a])
```

Here is the edited code:

```
def product_of_positives(seq):
    positives=[]       
    p=1        
    for a in range (len(seq)):            
        if seq[a] > 0:                
            positives.append(seq[a])      
    for i in range (len(positives)):          
        p=p*positives[i]        
        print(p)  

seq=[1,2,3,4,5]
product_of_positives(seq)
```

This would raise an error because the `.append()` is not expecting a `for` within its arguments.

Comment: Yes, that is because you are using parentheses instead of square brackets. Check my edit @thedancingman4321